# Calendar months are not getting equally distributed on X-Axis of recharts

Tags: recharts

I am trying to create a graph with recharts, where I want to distribute my whole data in 12 calendar months, the issue I am facing here is giving the timestamp for the 12th month(Dec) in the data, my graph is not calculating the Dec month.
Here is the code to the sandbox:
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wind-klgmmz?file=/src/SampleGraph.js)

Changing the end date with the month as "12" is not helpful as it will be considered as Jan, not Dec.
[image]

Comment: the enddate in code sandbox is only till 11th month.

Comment: The months are calculated from 0, considering 0 as Jan and 11th month as Dec.

Comment: issue is in the for loop of getticks function.

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-browser-gshgn0?file=/src/SampleGraph.js

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but It seems you have changed the endDate month from 11 -> 12, that's the actual issue

Comment: best possible solution seems to be 
const endDate = add(new Date(2022, 11, 15), {
    months: 1
  });
seems the upper cap is not inclusive so adding a month to enddate helped.